# How can I update the animation line of bone's transformation in UPBGE with python code?

Tags: python, animation, bones, game-engine

My concept is about extending the animation line dynamically by changing the bones' transformation in necessity in loop for one character that is rigged with bones for a whole game. That means, the animation will be played of one character or dedicated to bones once in loop, so the bones will be updated from scene to scene.
Can you tell me if that is possible, like in Unity 3d game engine, which has a predefined event in coding .NET called "late Update"?

Edit:

I found out a way to make the animation stuff dynamical with a bit coding. Not that hard, I was surprised.
The question is answered so far, but comments are still welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## X, Y, and Z location to set

cube1.location = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

## Set the keyframe with that location, and which frame.

cube1.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=1)

## For example repeat this!

cube1.location = (4.0, 1.0, 2.0)

## setting it for frame 12

cube1.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=12)

## Conclusion

More info about .keyframe_insert() can be found in Blender's manual.